# using firebase-admin in netlify function

Tags: node.js, firebase, grpc, firebase-admin, netlify

I am trying to use `firebase-admin` npm module in a Netlify cloud function. By default netlify-lambda packages the functions with Webpack, which breaks `firebase-admin` as it's not compatible with Webpack.
I tried using the alternate "zip n ship" method but even that doesn't works. From the error, it seems the `node_modules` generated on my machine are not working correctly on the machine where the function is deployed. Here is the error:

```
Error: The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'
```

Anyone who has made this work?

Comment: What version of node is netlify functions running? I thought I read it was AWS at `8.10` and I think gRPC needs a [higher version](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/grpc-js/package.json#L9) . You might want to check the node version or ask support. That is where I would start.

Comment: @talves I am already using version 8.

Comment: I don't think you can control the version of aws in netlify functions. You may want to shoot them an email. from their support page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Webpack to generate new package.json file into the lambda directory and install its dependencies, then run netlify-lambda as this tutorial shows [firebase-admin-with-netlify-lambda](https://medium.com/@saphidev/use-firebase-admin-with-netlify-lambda-functions-free-483d3b390e3a)